# Programmatically enabling Windows 8 Pro mobile broadband device

Tags: c#

## Background

The company I work on is developing a kiosk-like application for tablets running Windows 8 Pro (on desktop mode).  The user shouldn't be able to access anything that isn't the application itself: charms will be disabled, the taskbar will be hidden behind the application, etc.

This also means the user shouldn't be able to change network settings, leaving the responsability to keep the device always connected to us.  Up to now, I had success using the Mobile Broadband API to assure the device is connected whenever there's a mobile network available.  It'll detect disconnect events and try to connect again.

## The Problem

Although the user shouldn't be able to do it, I'm considering the case where the user follows this steps:

- User opens right-side charm,
- clicks on Settings,
- clicks on Network,
- clicks on More PC Settings,
- clicks on Wireless, and
- disables the mobile broadband device.

I would like to be able to revert this programmatically and enable it again.

## The Attempts

I have tried some different ways to force 3G being reenabled.  Most of them give me the same result: they supposedly enable the device without errors, but I still cannot use it.  [Enable-NetAdapter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134956.aspx) in Powershell doesn't throw errors, and the Enable method of [Win32_NetworkAdapter](http://blog.opennetcf.com/2008/06/24/disableenable-network-connections-under-vista/) appears to work, but no dice.

I thought maybe the method IMbnRadio::SetSoftwareRadioState could be what I'm after, but I can't get to it when the device is disabled.  The method IMbnInterfaceManager::GetInterfaces throws a COMException claiming the element could not be found (HRESULT = 0x80070490).

```
MbnInterfaceManager mbnInterfaceManager = new MbnInterfaceManager();
IMbnInterfaceManager interfaceManager = (IMbnInterfaceManager)mbnInterfaceManager;

// The following line throws a COMException:
IMbnInterface[] interfaces = (IMbnInterface[])interfaceManager.GetInterfaces(); 

mobileInterface = interfaces[0];
mobileRadio = (IMbnRadio)mobileInterface;

uint requestId;
mobileRadio.SetSoftwareRadioState(MBN_RADIO.MBN_RADIO_ON, out requestId);
```

Is there a way to override user preferences set on "More PC Settings?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a sketchy way to solve this.  **Keep in mind this is undocumented, wrong, shameless and immoral, and will probably break eventually**.  The client is aware of this, but prefers to keep the access to the OS limited.

The setting in case is saved in the Registry.  At least in the computers I've checked, it's stored in HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0022 in a key named RadioOff.

The Airplane Mode setting is also stored in the Registry, but in a different place.  It's at HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\RadioManagement\SystemRadioState in a key named (Default).

After changing these keys and rebooting, everything seems to work fine.  I'll repeat though: you really shouldn't be doing this, especially the Airplane Mode thing.

Comment: Hi @AndréRamaciotti. How did you find those registry keys. I need to find keys that control enabling/disabling cellular connections on a tablet computer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Alex, sorry for the late answer.  I exported the complete registry hierarchy, changed the device settings, reexported the registry hierarchy, then used a diff tool to compare them.